# Comparison between Android WebView programmatically and the XML-based Layout files

Tags: android, android-webview

1. When should I create a WebView programmatically and when just inflate it by using findViewById()?
2. What are the advantages / disadvantages?
3. Which layout should I use as the parent layout when I just need one View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would create it programmatically if you only need it for very short periods and not very often. Most of the time I always go with the findViewById() route.
2. The main advantage with inflating it is that it can be easier to tweak little settings and easier to troubleshoot issues. But your mileage will vary.
3. I use FrameLayout so I can add a progressbar over top like so;

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/sup_launcher">

    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/webView"/>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:visibility="gone"/>
</FrameLayout>
```